# Square root of matrix

Tags: matrices, diagonalization, symmetric-matrices

Let $A^2$ be a symmetric matrice such that the *spectral theorem* allows us to write 
$$A^2 = P\operatorname{Diag}(\lambda_1 \dots \lambda_n)P^T$$
Suppose $\forall i \in [\![ 1, n]\!], \lambda_i \geq 0$.

I want to know if the following proposition is true:
$$A^2 = P\operatorname{Diag}(\lambda_1 \dots \lambda_n)P^T \implies A = P\operatorname{Diag}(\sqrt{\lambda_1} \dots \sqrt{\lambda_n})P^T$$

Comment: yes, it is indeed true

Comment: Please notice that my answer was initially only half-true; I presented the correct one now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is partially wrong; see discussion below**
This is false. If you know that $A^2= \mathrm{diag}(x_1,...,x_n)$ in some basis, then in this basis $A=\mathrm{diag}( \pm \sqrt{x_1},....,\pm \sqrt{x_n})$. Thus in general knowing $A^2$ there are $2^n$ choices for (symmetric) $A$. Of course taking square roots becomes unique if you restrict attention to positive matrices.

**Correction** It was pointed out to me in the comments that answer above is wrong without additional assumptions. Let's take a closer look. We know that $A$ commutes with $A^2$, so (since both are diagonalizable), there exists a common eigenbasis. If $A^2$ has nondegenerate spectrum then this already implies that $A$ is diagonal in the same basis as $A^2$. Otherwise we can group eigenvalues into blocks, so that (perhaps after reshuffling rows and columns) $A^2= \mathrm{diag}(y_1,...,y_1,y_2,...,y_2,...,y_n,...y_k)$, where $y_i \neq y_j$ for $i \neq j$ and $y_i \geq 0$ is repeated $g_i$ times. Now $A$ has to leave each eigenspace of $A^2$ invariant, so it is a direct sum of $g_i \times g_i$ matrices of the form $\sqrt{y_i} S_i$, where $S_i^2 = 1$, $S_i^T = S_i$. For $g_i=1$ the only matrices of this form are $\pm 1$ (reproducing the previous answer), but in general this is not the only possibility. For example for $g_1 = 2$ there is the Pauli $x$ matrix $\sigma_x = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Your result works only if the $(x_i)$ are distinct; otherwise, even if $A$ is assumed to be symmetric, there are non-diagonal solutions in the form of orthogonal symmetries (up to a homothety).

Comment: @loupblanc thank you, I corrected mu answer.